# Lost the slots tool/option

Tags: modeling

[image]

There should be slots next to global but I cant find them.

Comment: What slots are you referring to? Where are you missing them in 2.79b or 2.8?

Answer (score 2):

> What slots are you referring to? Where are you missing them in 2.79b or 2.8? – gtzkw

He is probably referring to layers and the interface looks like 2.79b.

> There should be slots next to global but I cant find them. - Volt

Press *numpad/* or *View > View Global/Local*.

[image]